# Pipeline Performance of Summarization of PCollections of custom types - mean and median of properties

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My Apache-Beam/Dataflow pipeline builds keyed PCollections of custom types from pub/sub events. The pre-summarization output is now a `PCollection<KV<String, MyCustomObject>>`. Next I need to summarize this data for reports. The collections of structured objects can be very large and so out-of-memory exceptions are possible if I am not careful.

I see in the documentation that both Combine (Combine.globally with CombineFn) and CombineWithContext utilities are available. However, documentation and code samples are still very light.

In this final step of my pipeline - I need to summarize these large PCollections, but they are complex structured objects and I am not only calculating mean averages. I also want to calculate the median of some properties.

I can imagine how the samples work across N worker instances. There must be some kind of 'weighted average' getting calculated across worker instances by the framework, for example. But this will not work for median. Is this what CombineWithContext is for? Should be persisting the state of median arrays with context with side input/output? Or can this be achieved some other way using just Combine.globally?

Any code examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be answered here I think - https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html

Comment: Hello. Did it finally solve your issue? Can you post it as a full answer so other users of the community can benefit from it? Thank you!

Comment: No. I am still wrestling with this. But I think it may be a matter of learning how to ask a more precise question. I think at this point I would delete this question, but I don't see a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the [ApproximateQuantile](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.16.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ApproximateQuantiles.html) transform is what you need, if you are ok with getting the approximate median.

There is another transform [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.16.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sketching/TDigestQuantiles.html) that provides the same functionality that is based on a more advanced algorithm.

Comment: Thank you! This does appear to be the optimal approach from the performance perspective. At the very least, it is helpful for me to understand the theoretical context and that median calculation does present a special challenge. I am inclined to call this a correct answer, although I am still new to the field and not sure. I am not actually going to pursue a solution with this approach at this time, however, and so I'm inclined to leave this open for a bit longer to see if there is any consensus.

Comment: My current plan is to try a more simple aggregator/combineFn solution. In other words, the less cutting edge, albeit less performant brute force approach because I don't think the upper end of my scale requirements warrant the extra complexity. In my case, I can GroupByKey against a few different properties and time range. Then I am thinking that the actual size of the array that I need to split will not be too large. I am willing to sacrifice some perf to keep things simple. Does this make sense?

Comment: I believe if you are sure the dataset size is not too large for a GroupByKey and you can afford the cost, you can implement the "finding median" with exact result yourself. You can do it with (GroupByKey + a downstream ParDo) or implement your own CombineFn directly.